# Getting the value of an attribute based on its position/index inside @object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, attributes, indexing

I'm trying to figure out how to get the index value of an objects attribute. And after searching stack and the railsapi I'm still not sure how I should approach this

```
    @groups = Group.where(:group_id => 1).first
```

- Groups model would contain attribute :participant_id and has_many :participants

How would one be able to get a :participant_id based on its index?
For example how to get the First and Third :participant_id based on its position?

Something like:

```
= @group.participant_id(index position 1)
= @group.participant_id(index position 3)
```

Comment: Does your Group model have an `has_many :participants` relationship ?

Comment: Jef: Yes it has like   has_many :participants inside group model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL/ActiveRecord, you may use `limit` and `offset` methods applied to the "Group to Participants" relation:

```
# First
@group.participants.order(:id).offset(0).limit(1)
# Second
@group.participants.order(:id).offset(1).limit(1)
# First, second and third
@group.participants.order(:id).offset(0).limit(3)
```

Or, if you want to load all participants in a single SQL query :

```
@group.participants.order(:id)[index]
```

Or, a combination of both approaches.

Comment: Thanks  Diden't thought of using the offset, probably a bit intensive on the db but for now it seems a good solution to start with thx!